# VSCode Python Debugging Doesn't Honor Breakpoints When Using python.pythonPath

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

With an empty workspace settings (`settings.json`), I can use the classic python launch configuration to debug my file.  For example:

```
{
  "name": "Launch",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "stopOnEntry": true,
  "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/someFile.py",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "env": {},
  "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
  "debugOptions": [
    "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
    "WaitOnNormalExit",
    "RedirectOutput"
  ]
}
```

Great.  Stepping thru code works excellent (osx python 2.7).

I have a virtual environment created. I ran `virtualenv <vname>`.  All of my source lives in the `<vname>` dir, along with the bin, lib, etc folders that virtualenv created.

Now, I have set `"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/python"` in my VSCode settings (VSCode v1.16.0).  The python executes, but debugger points are not honored.

What'd I do wrong?  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Add below setting in launch.json file

```
"justMyCode": false,
```

Comment: My god, thank you a lot. I spent more than 2 hours to find a problem, and finally it works.

Answer (score 0):

Python path should be set:

```
"python.pythonPath": ${workspaceRoot}/<vname>/bin/python"
```

with `<vname>` is virtual environment directory, created by using `virtualenv <vname>`

Comment: as noted above, i moved my project files into <vname>.  the code executes fine, it just doesn't break.  are you suggesting that my convention is not permitted?